# Read specific lines from csv with highcharts

Tags: csv, highcharts

i have a weather server who generate csv files like this:

```
   Date,time,Temp. Innentemperatur,Temp. Aussentemperatur,Hum. Aussentemperatur,Regen,Wind,Wind Direction,Wind Gust
    ,,∞C,∞C,%,l/qm,km/h,∞,km/h

    ,,1,2,18,34,35,36,45,133
    01.03.2013,00:00,21.5,1.4,89.0,,1.8,285,3.6,1024.9
    01.03.2013,00:01,21.5,1.4,89.0,,1.8,285,3.6,1024.9
```

is that possible to read only specify lines?
Example:
Date & time & Hum. ?

Comment: There's nothing to do with `highcharts`. Split each line by `,` and get  the column you want from each line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, when you get data and use loop to push data to series.data array, then you can skip appropriate lines. I'd recommend to familiar with article about preprocessing data http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file